# Statistically comparing real-world data and predictions

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation, predictive-models, biostatistics

I don't often engage in statistics, so please excuse incorrect terminology or if I've missed something obvious.

Our team is working on animal morphological data. In summary, we have collected a bunch of "real world" morphological data (length and weight) from a population, and would like to compare it with the values that are estimated from an equation that has been established for that species. The equation takes the form of W = aLᵇ.

The point of this exercise is to determine if there is difference between the predicted values, and what is occurring within this population.

Where do I begin with this?

We have plotted this data, which visually indicates there are differences between the predictions and our data, but I do not know how to analyse this in a meaningful way.

Is a test of significance absolutely required here? Or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Hi Tim and Welcome to CrossValidated! By "...what is occurring within this population" do you refer to the sample data? Perhaps adding a picture of the problem would be useful. As far as I can tell you have a two-sample problem and a t-test or t confidence interval may be a starting point.

Comment: my 2 cents: formal significance testing will not improve intuition if graphics reveal a clear difference.

Answer (score 2):

Given the established equation, I am guessing you graphed log W against log L to see whether or not the transformed data appeared to show a linear relationship. You found (unspecified) differences.

In the usual significance testing setup, **before** collecting the data you have formed a view about where the formal model may fail if it does fail (this could be gleaned from other sources) and this determines both your 'null' hypothesis and your test statistic.

However, hypothesis tests where the test statistic is chosen *after* seeing the data are not valid tests. So to answer your question, formal significance testing is not required. Your example is more a case of exploratory data analysis in which you describe and measure the deviations from the theoretical model. You can still use p-values for your description if you wish, just don't claim any statistically significant results. Your comments could include, for example, a suggestion on an improvement to the model to take account of the differences you have observed. The improved model could be formally tested in a subsequent study.